# How to prevent webpage direct access without php script?

Tags: html, github

The problem concerning hosting a web app on the GitHub page. I am fully aware that GitHub page is only for hosting static web page and do not support PHP. The problem is I only want the people with my correct login id and password to access my web app. But people can simply access the content pages with URL without logging in. How to preclude direct access? Is it possible to do it without PHP?

Desired case:
home.html==> correct id and psw ==> contents.html

Current case:
URL for contents ==> contents.html

Comment: (https://jekyllrb.com/)

Comment: You realize anything in the browser is not secure. It is like using a combination lock and writing the combination on the back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript Validator

Check This one Username = `Gaurav` and Password = `password`

```css
.buttonlo {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.buttonre {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.buttonre,
.buttonlo {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Login Page</h1>
  <form name="login">
    Username<input class="box" type="text" name="userid" /> Password
    <input type="password" class="box" name="pswrd" />
    <input class=buttonlo type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login" />
    <input class="buttonre" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
  </form>
  <script language="javascript">
    function check(form) {

      if (form.userid.value == "Gaurav" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
        alert("Access Granted");
      } else {
        alert("Error Password or Username")
      }
    }
  </script>
  <p>username and password is in javascript section</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This isn't secure in the least

Comment: To make it secure, you then backend
while on github, this is the only option

Comment: or you can add the javascript code in a js library to hide it from attackers, like in jquery.js